# Change the trigger for FZF in VIM

Tags: vim, fzf

I am having trouble figuring out how to change the default trigger for fuzzy find within VIM.

The default trigger is :FZF

I would like the trigger to be :fzf

Thanks!

Comment: User-defined commands most always start with a capital, so using `:fzf` is impossible. The best you can do is `:Fzf`.

Answer (score 10):

You can add your own mapping for `fzf` in your `.vimrc`.

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-p> :fzf<CR>
```

This will call `:fzf` when you issue `Ctrl+P` in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an abbrev for the command line

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> fzf getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'fzf' ? 'FZF' : 'fzf'
```

then if you type `:fzf` followed by enter or followed by space it will be automatically swapped to `:FZF`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the only one that actually answers op's question.